# Mediawiki: Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties. Cannot access the database

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia

I believe this is not actually a connect issue, as I can see "title-invalid-e" and I can connect with the same credentials found in my LocalSettings.php file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

http://gwart.co.uk/

Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Try waiting a few minutes and reloading.

(Cannot access the database)

Backtrace:

```
#0 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(753): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->reportConnectionError()
#1 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(2653): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->getConnection(0, Array, false)
#2 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/localisation/LCStoreDB.php(54): wfGetDB(-1)
#3 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/localisation/LocalisationCache.php(410): LCStoreDB->get('en', 'deps')
#4 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/localisation/LocalisationCache.php(456): LocalisationCache->isExpired('en')
#5 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/localisation/LocalisationCache.php(375): LocalisationCache->initLanguage('en')
#6 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/localisation/LocalisationCache.php(294): LocalisationCache->loadSubitem('en', 'messages', 'title-invalid-e...')
#7 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/languages/Language.php(2640): LocalisationCache->getSubitem('en', 'messages', 'title-invalid-e...')
#8 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(984): Language->getMessage('title-invalid-e...')
#9 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(942): MessageCache->getMessageForLang(Object(LanguageEn), 'title-invalid-e...', false, Array)
#10 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(884): MessageCache->getMessageFromFallbackChain(Object(LanguageEn), 'title-invalid-e...', false)
#11 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/Message.php(1312): MessageCache->get('title-invalid-e...', false, Object(LanguageEn))
#12 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/Message.php(864): Message->fetchMessage()
#13 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/Message.php(956): Message->toString('text')
#14 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/title/MalformedTitleException.php(49): Message->text()
#15 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/title/MediaWikiTitleCodec.php(297): MalformedTitleException->__construct('title-invalid-e...', '')
#16 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/Title.php(3752): MediaWikiTitleCodec->splitTitleString('', 0)
#17 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/Title.php(378): Title->secureAndSplit()
#18 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(83): Title::newFromURL('')
#19 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(140): MediaWiki->parseTitle()
#20 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(778): MediaWiki->getTitle()
#21 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(517): MediaWiki->main()
#22 /var/www/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/index.php(42): MediaWiki->run()
#23 {main}
```

Comment: Thanks for viewing the question. It would be helpful to get some feedback for the close vote, if I can update the question at all I would love to do so.

Comment: why do you think it's using the credentials from LocalSettings.php the same way you do?

Comment: This is where the DB settings are stored. Is it not?

Comment: It seems fairly likely that this is actually a DB access issue where the wiki can't log into the database with its credentials. It tries to load a message about invalid titles from the localisation cache, which falls back to the database (`LCStoreDB.php`), and then that fails